# In Android Studio, How to get other application's package names in logcat panel?

Tags: android, android-studio

The following is my logcat view in Android studio

[image]

I found that I can only see the package name which is developed by me. For other applications in System. The packages name is shown as "?". How can I display it's actual package name in logcat view?

For now, I have a workaround to get the package name. That is to use adb shell. For example, I am curious about the pid 6014:

```
$ adb shell
shell@hammerhead:/ $ ps | grep 6014
u0_a108   6014  213   1591320 44892 sys_epoll_ 00000000 S com.hujiang.hjclass
```

The package name is **com.hujiang.hjclass** in this case. However, I am looking for a more native way to get package name. Any idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is direct way to see it. But you can find it by using [York Logcat Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sked.yorklogcat) and York [Logcat Android Studio Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8359?pr=androidstudio).